# function that returns a IEnumerable<T> with yield return

Tags: winforms, recursion, controls, parent

I have a function that only returns the first parent item.

```
        public static T FindControlParent<T>(this Control control) where T : Control
    {
        T parent = default;
        if (control.Parent != null)
        {
            if (control.Parent.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                return (T)control.Parent;
            }
            return FindControlParent<T>(control.Parent);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

I have a button, which is inside two panels, I would like a function that returns a list of the two panels of the button.
something like

Form>panel1>panel2>GroupBox>button

var panelsFinded = FindControlParents<Panel>(button1);
//values: panel1, panel2

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, someone correct me if it can get better

```
     public static IEnumerable<T> FindControlParent2<T>(Control control) 
where T : Control
    {          
        if (control != null)
        {
            Control parent = control.Parent;
            if (parent is T)                
                yield return(T)control.Parent;                

            foreach (var i in FindControlParent2<T>(parent.Parent))                
                yield return i;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could be probably simplified in `var ancestor = control?.Parent; while (ancestor != null) { if (ancestor is T) yield return (T)ancestor; ancestor = ancestor.Parent; }`

Comment: your code was the solution, mine is giving exception in the sub parents for some reason, thanks